# Use cURL XPOST in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, curl

I have been provided with the following cURL function:

```js
curl -XPOST -u 'USERNAME:PASSWORD' http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/virksomhed/_search -d '
{
    "query":{"term":{"Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer":"30714024"}}
}' | python -mjson.tool
```

How can I convert this to be used on my WordPress site? (I need to use this in my JavaScript)

The goal is to get information on a company in JSON, which I'll convert to an object.

There is a site that does this (in a slightly different way, https://cvrapi.dk/documentation), but I need to do it natively on my own website with my own Username and Password.

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Your Wordpress site is using PHP as the server language, and possibly [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) or [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) as the server application. It is therefore, by default not capable of running JS.

## How is your JS running?

Basically, the web-browser of the user is communicating with the server via the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)/[HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) protocol and gets some responses. The response sent by the server may contain `<script>` tags, either by defining the `src` where the js file could be downloaded from or the actual Javascript code as the inner HTML of the `<script>`. The web-browser in turn is able to execute Javascript.

## Is it a good idea to run your JS in the browser?

In this specific case, **NO, NO, NO**. You have very private credentials inside the Javascript code you have, which should **NEVER** be sent to a client browser. More broadly speaking, there is nothing wrong with running Javascript code in the user's browser, but in your specific case, due to the secrecy of your particular code, due to the fact that username and password are inside it, you should avoid doing that, while other, less secretive Javascript code can safely run in the user's browser.

## Before adding support for running Javascript

PHP has the [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function, which converts a JSON into a PHP object (or a PHP array, depending on how you call it, read the docs for more information). You have support for [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) in PHP, so it is unnecessary to run JS code in order to execute cURL. Btw, cURL can be executed by native [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) as well, see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/curl-command-in-linux-with-examples/) for example. So, making technical changes just to allow your server to run cURL requests via Javascript by itself is an overcomplication of your problem and is unnecessary. If there are other things you need to do with Javascript as well, then that's another story, because you are already able to either run cURL-based features directly from PHP, or to write your cURL command as a CLI command (or file) and [run that via PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). So there are two neat and simpler solutions than the one you intend to apply.

## Running Javascript

If you need to run your Javascript code and retrieve its results from Wordpress (PHP, to be more specific), then you will need to set up a [Javascript-based server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/development_environment) and write your own small Javascript project that does the cURL for you and then run your `npm` command via CLI in your PHP to get the result. But, again, this is overcomplication and you have simpler, neater, better solutions than setting up another server to handle something that your server already handles well.